# How do I send a file to download with AJAX in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I’m trying to cut the plugin for WordPress. Help, who than can, please 
The JavaScript data is taken from the backend and returned to PHP, which creates a file on the server. The task is to give it to the user in the browser. Old script gave it without problems download.php:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$name;');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
if (ob_get_contents()) ob_end_clean();
flush();
readfile($name);
```

But for security, you must prohibit direct access, OK:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
```

Accordingly, the call to AJAX hung on success began to open an empty window:

```
$.ajax ( {

    type: "POST",

    url: myAyax.ajax_urls.write_url,//Here, the function hooked via the hook to admin-ajax.php is called

    data: {
        ids: [], //This is some kind of data
        action: 'write_file_server', //We pass the hook. Who writes a file with data to the server.
    },

    success: function ( result ) {
        window.location = myAyax.ajax_urls.download_url //Here was a link to the direct call download.php (see above)
    }

} );
```

Tried to cause, in function caused through a hook: include (‘download.php’);
Called, sends the contents and code to the buffer 200, but does not swing;)
The link in succes-e on the file opens its contents, and also does not swing, of course 
Help ideas, please.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your javascript formatting a little, and it seems to be working for me. Is that what you were looking for?

```
$.ajax ( {

    type: "POST",

    url: myAyax.ajax_urls.write_url,//Here, the function hooked via the hook to admin-ajax.php is called

    data: {
        ids: [], //This is some kind of data
        action: 'write_file_server', //We pass the hook. Who writes a file with data to the server.
    },

    success: function ( result ) {
        window.location = myAyax.ajax_urls.download_url //Here was a link to the direct call download.php (see above)
    }

} );
```

Comment: No errors in console.Status Code:200 OK Open new blank screen.

Comment: if add in php script in function 'write_file_server' include(download.php); If it also calls a white screen and code 200.

Comment: myAyax.ajax_urls.download_url link to download.php

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :) I need to do a hook on the Get request, and call it with a link:

```
window.location = window.location.href+'&filename=file.file';
```